# Delete Every line with that Word

Tags: regex, notepad++, replace

I want to delete the whole line if the line contains a specific word for example "**cat**".

If "**cat**" is in this line, delete the whole line!

*Example* 
Before

```
0123456789$$"!§%   CAT   $"!$&()&0912WORDS
53DAD$"§$DSFC09243 DOG %$§%
KLJ0963@    CAT   - 8953"""!
```

After how it should look like

```
53DAD$"§$DSFC09243 DOG %$§%
```

Which expression I have to use?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not necessarily a regex needed here

1. Go to the search menu Ctrl+F (Strg+F, bzw. *Suchen - Suchen*)
2. On the "Mark" tab, enter the word in the "Find what" field (Im "Vorkommnisse markieren" tab, das Scuhwort in "Suchen nach" eingeben)
3. Check "Bookmark line" (Haken bei Lesezeichen setzen)
4. Press "Mark all" ("Alle suchen")
5. Goto *Search - Bookmark - Remove Bookmarked lines* (Im Menü *Suchen - Lesezeichen - Zeilen mit Lesezeichen löschen* auswählen)

==> you are done

Comment: That will give problems for someone actually using bookmarks though.

Comment: Sounds like a great Idea, but not really helpful for me who do not use notepad++ in englisch.

Comment: Then it gets difficult in Notepad++, since the regexes are very limited there. Another possibility would be to replace those lines with the empty string and in a second string remove all empty rows using the extended replace mode. But this would also remove "wanted" empty rows.

Comment: @Eule2000 should not be too difficult to translate this into your language. The "Mark" tab is the fourth tab in the Find dialogue, the rest should be quite straight forward to find.

Comment: @Eule2000 whats your language, in german I would be able to guide you. Otherwise just change your language under settings - preferences to English and back.

Comment: @Stema would be nice if you can tell me that 5 steps in german.

Comment: @Eule2000 Ich habs in der Antwort ergänzt.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like:

[a-z]*cat[a-z]*

I don't know if you have spaces or other special caracters...

Comment: [a-z| |.|,|0-9]\*cat[a-z| |.|,|0-9]\*

Answer (score 0):

It is a two step process in notepad++. First do a regex replace

```
Find what: ^(.*?)(cat)(.*?)$
Replace with:
```

Next do a extended replace with

```
Find what: \r\n\r\n
Replace with: \r\n
```

Assuming your file was created on Windows. However this will also remove all lines that previously had no content.

Edit: Probably better to do the bookmark thing the other guy suggested.

Comment: The first Find step even dont work. It dont find "cat" in a line

Comment: Do you have regex select? I tested it with Notepad++ v5.9.5 and it finds "cat" for me.

Comment: Didn't work for me either. Removing the ?s did it, though. ^(.*)(cat)(.*)$