# How can I delete certain type of lines?

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I noticed Notepad++ has regex search. What I want to do is delete every line in the file that contains a certain string. I've tried the following expression: `^.+?MyString.+$` but it leaves the line, i want to delete the line too.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. Now what have you tried ?

Comment: `^.+?MyString.+$` this selects my line, but it leaves the line, i want to delete the line too.

Comment: I would have liked to see the answer with regex, but his solution worked too. If someone offers a reg-ex based solution I'll accept that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty similar to the question here: [delete-every-line-with-that-word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387032/delete-every-line-with-that-word)

1. Go to the search menu Ctrl+F
2. On the "Mark" tab, enter the string in the "Find what" field
3. Check "Bookmark line"
4. Press "Mark all"
5. Goto Search - Bookmark - Remove Bookmarked lines

You will however need to not be using bookmarks for that file.

Comment: Indeed. I wish I found that before... thanks!